# Very easy SQL function returns boolean 1 (true) instead of resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have this function

```
function query($query)
{
     return mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())
}
```

but when I call it like

```
$last = query("SELECT * FROM jubox ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 45");
```

$last returns 1

```
 echo $last; //1
```

What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT:

I want to return RESOURCE id NOT DATA

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can get the resource ID (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). Why would you want to do that?

Comment: beause mysql_fetch_assoc then gives me Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/jukebox/fronta.... and i was just debugging (by echo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix `return` and `x OR y`

```
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test', $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));
mysql_query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE jubox_so (id int auto_increment, primary key(id))') or die(mysql_error($mysql));

$last = query("SELECT * FROM jubox_so ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 45");
echo $last;

function query($query)
{
    $v = mysql_query($query);
    if ( !$v ) {
        die(myql_error());
    }
    return $v;
}
```

prints (something like) `Resource id #6` as expected instead of 1 (which was caused by the bool->string conversion for echo)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you are trying to echo out a resource, which returns 1 if valid (if echoing a resource, it does indeed echo 1)

You need to use a mysql_fetch_* function to get the data

Comment: but my point is to return resource id. How can I do it? IT works for me in my other project

Comment: it is probaly because 1 is your current resource ID then

Comment: @genesis I think what you need to do is "*to use a mysql_fetch_\* function to get the data*"

Comment: NO I DO NOT ! I want to use it like $result = query("SELECT * FROM ..."); while($row = mysql_fetch_.....){}

Comment: WELL WHERE IS YOUR PROBLEM THEN? You have a resource, just **don't** echo it because it will be converted to a string...

Comment: because mysql_fetch_assoc gives me "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/jukebox/fr...."

Answer (score 1):

Look into mysql_fetch_* functions. They return actual rows for you. The mysql_query returns a link_identifier that can be used to fetch the results. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php for the different functions available.

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing the result right? In case of a select this is a mysql result object and not true or false (like with update or insert). What you get is a  [result resource](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). You need to use functions as [fetch_assoc](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to explore that result.

Comment: I think you didn't get me. I'm not amateur in PHP but this is very strange case when it does return bool instead of resource id ...

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason why you print out '1', is because your query result of an error and then it is the returned value of the die() that you get back.
Check you query, copy and paste it in phpMyAdmin for exemple, and look for an error

Comment: it worked in phpmyadmin, did you see that code ? There isn't syntax code!